# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'controller'

Tags: python, tkinter, controller, project

Getting the following error:

```
TypeError:  __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'controller'.
```

I somehow cannot seem to get this to work. If you require any more information please leave a comment down below.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (App, pag2):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
           self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master,controller):
        master.geometry("790x596")


        photo = PhotoImage(file="Naamloos.png")
        self.w = w = Label (master, image=photo)
        w.photo = photo
        w.pack()

        self.controller = controller
        self.hello_b = Button(master,text="Actuele vertrekken",command=lambda: controller.show_frame("pag2"), height=3,
                          width=18,fg= "white",bg = "#00339C")
        self.hello_b.place(x=178, y=387)

class pag2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, controller):
        master.geometry("790x596")

        self.controller = controller
        photo = PhotoImage(file="Naamloos2.png")
        self.w = w = Label (master, image=photo)
        w.photo = photo
        w.pack()

        self.hello_b = Button(master,text="Actuele vertrekken",command=lambda: controller.show_frame("App"), height=3,
                          width=18,fg= "white",bg = "#00339C")
        self.hello_b.place(x=178, y=387)

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Kaartautomaat")
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Comment: Where are you getting the error at?

Comment: So, the error is telling you that you are missing one argument (named `controller`), and looking at where you instantiate the class (`app = App(root)`)  you are indeed missing one argument. What about that isn't clear?

Answer (score 1):

You declared `App.__init__` to take two arguments (`master` and `controller`), but you only supply one when you call it (`app = App(root)`). You need to supply an appropriate second argument to that call.

```
c = ???
app = App(root, c)
```

Comment: how would I go past doing this?

Comment: @JopCorver "past doing" what? Supplying the right number of arguments? You can't. If you declared yourself the `App` constructor as taking two (three if you count `self`) arguments, which you did by writing `def __init__(self,master,controller):`, then you *must* pass it two arguments.